# Expo sdk 48 - Android build failure - "FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures"

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I've been developing and publishing with expo / react native for more than 2 years.
Suddenly building for Android fails.
I just upgraded to the latest sdk, reinstalled node modules.
Building for iOS works.
But for Android, build fails at the "Run gradlew" step.

Here are the logs of that state:

> Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
> Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
> Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
> ..
> Configure project :expo-updates
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
> 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/android/build.gradle' line: 78
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-updates'.
>   Could not find method boolish() for arguments [true] on DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=21, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=31, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=31, versionName=0.18.5, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=SigningConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=/home/expo/.android/debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null}, resConfig=[], buildConfigFields={EX_UPDATES_NATIVE_DEBUG=com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl@50e3c81e}, resValues={}, proguardFiles=[], consumerProguardFiles=[/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/android/proguard-rules.pro], manifestPlaceholders={}, wearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig$AgpDecorated.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.

> 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
>   compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.

> BUILD FAILED in 2m 14s

I have checked that compileSdkVersion is specified in expo-updates.
I have removed and reinstalled expo-updates.
But nothing works.

Do you have any idea ?

Seems related to this [github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17710)

Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same issue. What worked for me was the following:

1. Change java version to 17.

I was using openjdk@20, and I changed it to openjdk@17 using homebrew (I'm on a mac. If you are too, remember to point the soft link /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk to /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk).

2. Upgrade expo SDK to version 49 with: $ npx expo upgrade.
3. Delete /android folder on project.

I did this to make sure everything is builded again from scratch.

4. Run $ npx expo run:android.
5. If that still doesn't work, make sure you are using gradle version 8.0.1.

This is set up in file /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. The distributionUrl should be:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip

Hope this helps!